# Check if the user is logged-in in a theme

Tags: theming, 8

In Drupal 7 we can simply check if the current user is logged-in in a theme by checking `$GLOBAL['user']->uid` or  using [`user_is_logged_in()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_is_logged_in/7.x).

How can I check if a user is logged-in in a page template, in Drupal 8?

A solution is to manually check in `hook_preprocess_page()`, but since this is very popular, I think  Drupal provides something by default for the Twig theme engine.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you just need to verify the current user is logged-in, you can use `$variables['logged_in']`, which is generally available in all the template files.

For example, the [mark.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21mark.html.twig/8.2.x) file uses the following code, although the only documented variable is `status`.

```
{% if logged_in %}
  {% if status is constant('MARK_NEW') %}
    <span class="marker">{{ 'New'|t }}</span>
  {% elseif status is constant('MARK_UPDATED') %}
    <span class="marker">{{ 'Updated'|t }}</span>
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

The variable is explicitly documented in other template files, such as [html.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21html.html.twig/8.2.x), [page.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21page.html.twig/8.2.x), and [node.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21templates%21node.html.twig/8.2.x).

The variable is available in all the template files, since it is initialized in `_template_preprocess_default_variables()` that invokes [`user_template_preprocess_default_variables_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_template_preprocess_default_variables_alter/8.2.x) (an implementation of `hook_template_preprocess_default_variables_alter()`), which contains the following code.

```
  $user = \Drupal::currentUser();

  $variables['user'] = clone $user;
  // Remove password and session IDs, since themes should not need nor see them.
  unset($variables['user']->pass, $variables['user']->sid, $variables['user']->ssid);

  $variables['is_admin'] = $user->hasPermission('access administration pages');
  $variables['logged_in'] = $user->isAuthenticated();
```

`_template_preprocess_default_variables()` is called by `template_preprocess()`, which is the function called for theme hooks implemented as templates; this guarantees the variable is available in all the template files.

Keep in mind that [macros don't have access to the current template variables](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html), so trying to access `logged_in` in the code of a macro would not have any effect.
Between the template files used from Drupal core modules, the ones using a macro are:

- [menu.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21menu.html.twig/8.6.x)

  ```
    {% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
      {% import _self as menus %}
      {% if items %}
        {% if menu_level == 0 %}
          <ul{{ attributes }}>
        {% else %}
          <ul>
        {% endif %}
        {% for item in items %}
          <li{{ item.attributes }}>
            {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
            {% if item.below %}
              {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
            {% endif %}
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
    {% endmacro %}
  ```
- [book-tree.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21book%21templates%21book-tree.html.twig/8.6.x)

  ```
    {% macro book_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
      {% import _self as book_tree %}
      {% if items %}
        {% if menu_level == 0 %}
          <ul{{ attributes }}>
        {% else %}
          <ul>
        {% endif %}
        {% for item in items %}
          <li{{ item.attributes }}>
            {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
            {% if item.below %}
              {{ book_tree.book_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
            {% endif %}
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
    {% endmacro %}
  ```
- [menu--toolbar.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21toolbar%21templates%21menu--toolbar.html.twig/8.6.x)

  ```
    {% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
      {% import _self as menus %}
      {% if items %}
        {% if menu_level == 0 %}
          <ul{{ attributes.addClass('toolbar-menu') }}>
        {% else %}
          <ul class="toolbar-menu">
        {% endif %}
        {% for item in items %}
          {%
            set classes = [
              'menu-item',
              item.is_expanded ? 'menu-item--expanded',
              item.is_collapsed ? 'menu-item--collapsed',
              item.in_active_trail ? 'menu-item--active-trail',
            ]
          %}
          <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
            {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
            {% if item.below %}
              {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
            {% endif %}
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
    {% endmacro %}
  ```

For example, changing the last macro with the following code would not have the expected result.

```
{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    {% if menu_level == 0 %}
      <ul{{ attributes.addClass('toolbar-menu') }}>
    {% else %}
      <ul class="toolbar-menu">
    {% endif %}
    {% for item in items %}
      {%
        set classes = [
          'menu-item',
          logged_in ? 'menu-item--logged-in-user',
          item.is_expanded ? 'menu-item--expanded',
          item.is_collapsed ? 'menu-item--collapsed',
          item.in_active_trail ? 'menu-item--active-trail',
        ]
      %}
      <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
        {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
        {% if item.below %}
          {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
        {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: `The variable is surely available in all the template files` I am afraid you are wrong regarding this. If the template does not mention it in the comments, there must be a reason, right? Because I tried on **[menu.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!templates!menu.html.twig/8.2.x)** (which does not mention it in the comments) and did not work. While using Twig Extender it works.

Comment: `_template_preprocess_default_variables()` is called for every template Drupal outputs, so the variables it adds are present in all the template files. Documentation doesn't document all the default variables, as far as I can see.

Comment: @kiamlaluno whenever you have free time, try `{% if logged_in %}` on menu.html.twig and you'll see it doesn't work. Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can with the [Twig Extender](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_extender) module. Quote from its project page:

> Add a simple plugin system to add new twig extensions (Filter and
>   Functions). Provides a new service provider for "twig.extensions" to
>   add new plugins.
>
> **Function: is_user_logged_in**
>
> Check if user is logged in.
>
> ```
> {% if user_is_logged_in() %}
> Hello user
> {% else %}
> Please login
> {% endif %}
> ```

Comment: only 57 use and beta :(. maybe thee better solution is `    $vars['is_login']  = !\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous();
` in preprocess_page ? what is your opinion?

Comment: There is no need of a module for that functionality, since Drupal core has already it. See my answer.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes, I agree with you, this requirement is very popular and I was sure drupal had provided something for it.

Answer (score 2):

For everybody trying to use `logged_in` from menu.twig.html; you need to call it from outside the `menus.menu_links()` macro as the `logged_in` variable is out of scope within the macro.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the user is authenticated like so:

For example, I have created the following function in themename.theme.

```
# Function to get user logged info
function tropical_preprocess_page(&$variables){
  // if user is authenticated
  if($variables['user']->isAuthenticated()){
    # gets username
  $user_logged_in_name = $variables['user']->getDisplayName();
  # creates value to ouput in the DOM & capitalize first letter
  $variables['user_logged_in_name'] = ucfirst($user_logged_in_name);

  # gets user email
  $user_email = $variables['user']->getEmail();
  $variables['user_email'] = $user_email;

  // get user picture
  $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
  $variables['user_picture'] = $user->get('user_picture')->entity->url();

  // Check if user is logged in
  $user_logged = $variables['user']->isAuthenticated();
  $variables['user_logged'] = $user_logged;
  }
}
```

After that, you can create the logic within the Twig file like so:

```
<div class="user-logged-greeting">
  {% if user_logged %}
    <h2>Welcome back, {{ user_logged_in_name }}!</h2>
    <p>The email for this user is: <strong>{{ user_email }}<strong></p>
    <img src="{{ user_picture }}" width="50" height="50">
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

If the user is logged in, you will get the greeting message along with username, email & avatar picture. If user is not logged in, it won't show up anything.

Let me know if that helps and/or if I can edit this post for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't that the variable doesn't exist in the template file, but rather that it isn't available in the macro.  You can fix this via passing it through:

{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level, logged_in) %}

Then if you have a signin menu item, something like:

{% if item.title == 'Sign In' %}
   {% if not logged_in %}
      Go to login
      
   {% endif %}
{% endif %}

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I moved my login-sensitive button "Login" outside the menu macro. So the twig variable `logged_in` which is not in scope inside the macro could be used again.

Before moving the login-sensitive button (which did not work):

```
{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    {% if menu_level == 0 %}
<ul{{ attributes.addClass('menu') }}>
  {% else %}
  <ul class="menu">
    {% endif %}
    {% for item in items %}
...
    {% endfor %}

    {% if logged_in %}
    <li class="menu-item register">
      <a href="/user" data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>" class="btn btn-light">{{ 'My user account'|t }}</a>
    </li>
    {% else %}
    <li class="menu-item register">
      <a href="/user/login" data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>" class="btn btn-light">{{ 'Login'|t }}</a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>

  {% endif %}
  {% endmacro %}
```

After moving the login-sensitive button (works for me):

```
{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    {% if menu_level == 0 %}
<ul{{ attributes.addClass('menu') }}>
  {% else %}
  <ul class="menu">
    {% endif %}
    {% for item in items %}
...
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{% if logged_in %}
  <li class="menu-item register">
    <a href="/user" data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>" class="btn btn-light">{{ 'My user account'|t }}</a>
  </li>
{% else %}
  <li class="menu-item register">
    <a href="/user/login" data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>" class="btn btn-light">{{ 'Login'|t }}</a>
  </li>
{% endif %}
</ul>
```